# Why I do not have gear icon or cogwheel the sign in button on my on the login (username) page?

Tags: 22.04, wayland, display-manager

I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Gnome 42.9, windowing system X11.  I try to use Wayland, but I can't switch to it because I do not have gear icon or cogwheel the sign in button on my on the login (username) page.

[image]
[image]

My settings:

[/etc/gdm3/custom.conf](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop):

```
    # GDM configuration storage
    #
    # See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=true

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/gdm3


 ps -e | grep tty
 2286 tty2     00:00:00 gdm-x-session
 2288 tty2     00:03:01 Xorg
 2340 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-session-b


ps -e | grep X
2288 tty2     00:03:03 Xorg
```

sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

```
# Disable wayland when nvidia modeset is disabled or when drivers are a lower
# version than 470,
# For versions above 470 but lower than 510 prefer Xorg,
# Above 510, prefer Wayland.
KERNEL!="nvidia_drm", GOTO="gdm_nvidia_drm_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="module", GOTO="gdm_nvidia_drm_end"
ACTION!="add", GOTO="gdm_nvidia_drm_end"
# disable wayland if nvidia-drm modeset is not enabled
ATTR{parameters/modeset}!="Y", GOTO="gdm_disable_wayland"
# disable wayland for nvidia drivers versions lower than 470
ATTR{version}=="4[0-6][0-9].*|[0-3][0-9][0-9].*|[0-9][0-9].*|[0-9].*", GOTO="gdm_disable_wayland"
# For nvidia drivers versions Above 510, prefer Xorg by default
ATTR{version}=="[5-9][1-9][0-9].*", GOTO="gdm_prefer_xorg"
# For nvidia drivers versions 470-495, prefer Xorg by default
GOTO="gdm_prefer_xorg"
LABEL="gdm_nvidia_drm_end"

GOTO="gdm_end"

LABEL="gdm_prefer_xorg"
#RUN+="/usr/libexec/gdm-runtime-config set daemon PreferredDisplayServer xorg"
GOTO="gdm_end"

LABEL="gdm_disable_wayland"
#RUN+="/usr/libexec/gdm-runtime-config set daemon WaylandEnable false"
GOTO="gdm_end"

LABEL="gdm_end"
```

My GPU : NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 770]  uses

```
nvidia-smi
Tue Aug 22 14:06:23 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.199.02   Driver Version: 470.199.02   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 23%   46C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    189MiB /  1996MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Does it mean that my [GPU is not compatybile with wayland](https://wiki.debian.org/Wayland#Hardware_requirements)?
What should I do ?

Comment: did you try `Log Out` then log back in? The icon usually appears at that point when you select your username

Comment: @graham Yes, I have add next image ( login)

Answer (score 0):

This indeed means your current GPU is not compatible with Wayland. NVidia support for Wayland is rather recent and still incomplete.

> What should I do ?

Continue to use Xorg.

Comment: What about this : https://github.com/danvd/wlroots-eglstreams/issues/22

Comment: I guess this illustrates my point of "early support"?

Answer (score -1):

That's not true, the answer by [@vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/users/558158/vanadium) is total bs. The OP is just missing the `gnome-session-flashback` package. How can an icon presence/absence be related to a hardware component? In the main login screen even more! C'mon, we're not on iOS.